# Windows 7 not showing up in boot after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu and upon bootup there is no GRUB, bootloader, or anything. I tried holding down Shift while booting, that brought up GRUB but it did not display Windows 7. I know that Windows 7 is still on the disc, because I can view the partition from Ubuntu. I'd appreciate any help y'all can give.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot into Ubuntu, mount your Windows drive, open Terminal (Control+Alt+T), and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answer doesn't work, try to boot Ubuntu as a live CD and run boot-repair.  It's fixed every boot problem I had.
http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/