# No option to boot windows after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader

I already have windows installed and I just installed Ubuntu and I was expecting that it will ask me which OS to boot after startup but it didn't.

I refer the link but didn't work [Windows 7 not showing up in boot after installing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454123/windows-7-not-showing-up-in-boot-after-installing-ubuntu).

I set the option of Erase disk and install Ubuntu. But it says currently has no detected operating system.
[image]

How to set this option now. I already have Ubuntu installed and I am not getting option to boot windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 1):

try the below command :-

```
sudo os-prober

sudo update-grub

reboot
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nop didn't work.

Comment: I set the option of Erase disk and install Ubuntu. But it says currently has no detected operating system. Link to image as i can't upload because of less than 10 reputation.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xCC50zlFkzRms3c3lQNm9STUk/view?usp=sharing  . So you think it formatted my Windows.

Comment: In that case, it has removed Windows. In case you wished to dual boot you have to chose "Something else". It will give you options to partition and you should proceed.

Comment: Can I recover some of the content of Windows.

Comment: Yes, from your backups.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installation CD of Windows, you can repair the bootloader of Windows with the help of command line, typing the following code:

> bootrec /fixmbr

It will restore the Windows bootloader for you.

Comment: I set the option of Erase disk and install Ubuntu. But it says currently has no detected operating system. Link to image as i can't upload because of less than 10 reputation.drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xCC50zlFkzRms3c3lQNm9STUk/… . Still I can restore the Windows